# A contact not showing in my phone but in WhatsApp

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I wanted to delete a contact from my phone, but to my surprise, when I searched for their name in my phone's contacts, nothing showed up. No one with that name or number was in my contact list. Their name, profile picture, status, etc. are all showing normally on WhatsApp and Telegram though. I tried to clear the cache for WhatsApp and also refreshed the contact list. Nothing changed.

I was curious and checked a few other contacts that I saved through WhatsApp. They don't show up in my phone's contacts either. So I have their number but somehow cannot delete them.

Does anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp makes a copy of your contacts, so they are separate.  Depending on your Phone and Android, you may or may not be able to see these.

But you can use [My Phone Explorer](https://myphone-explorer.en.softonic.com/) app.  It has a Windows companion App, where you can see all the contacts and their details and you can delete them from there.  I am not associated with this app in any way.

However, you don't need to delete the contact.  If you dont want to interact with them, just block them in WhatsApp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there an alternative for mac users? I don't have access to a Windows computer.